# Efficient way to increase java jar output file

Tags: java, jar, size

I want to manipulate the size of output jar files for some test cases where I need to have multiple jar files with different sizes.

I have been successful with that by creating simple java class that has very long string. Unfortunately the extra long string, has increased the total output jar size by just some kbs. The eclipse started to lag when I tried to clone that string, so I ended up with copying that java class and then the packages. In the end I had my 600kb~ jar file, but it looks very messy. I'd like to know some way to do it in one file, something like initialize some very big constats/enums etc, that wont be initialized runtime, but saved in output file and increase its size.

Comment: A Jar is just a Zip file.  You can put anything you like in it.

Answer (score 0):

JAR files are ZIP files. ZIP is a compression format. Random data cannot be compressed. So you can just add Strings which contain random characters.
In opposite repeated Strings can be compressed very well.
You can also use digits of PI. http://www.piday.org/million/